# Passing argument to bash -c shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I need to execute a shell script on cloud shell.
So I am downloading the shell script using the curl command from the cloud storage and then trying to execute the same

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://storage.googleapis.com/<Some_bucket>/rules.sh)"
```

I need to pass 2 parameters to this script rules.sh.

I tried below 2 ways :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://storage.googleapis.com/<Some_bucket>/rules.sh)" param1 param2
```

and

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://storage.googleapis.com/<Some_bucket>/rules.sh) param1 param2"
```

But both of them did not worked.

Let me know how I should pass the parameters ?

Comment: The first param becomes `$0`, so you need to pass a dummy before the things that become `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: So you want `bash -c "$(curl ...)" bash param1 param2`, where the extra `bash` becomes `$0` so error messages written by the shell print `bash: ...`. It's also reasonable to use `_` as a placeholder, because it's commonly recognized, even though it'll make error messages look worse.

Comment: Thanks Charles, it worked by using the below suggestion !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
curl -fsSL https://storage.googleapis.com/<Some_bucket>/rules.sh | bash -s param1 param2
```

Comment: Thanks .. It worked !!
Can you also help me with some documentations were I can learn these stuff ...
I am really bad in remembering these alphabets we use in unix , for eg : here -s , I don't know why we have to use it !!

Comment: Think "stdin" re: `-s`.

Comment: @AnuragKumarPandey `man bash` is a good documentation for `bash`